# jquery mobile. form validator (with a select)

Tags: jquery-mobile, select, jquery-validate, validation

im trying to validate a form like this:

```
<input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" data-mini="true" required />
<select id="comboPaises" name="comboPaises" data-mini="true">
 <option value="0" disabled="disabled" selected="">Selecciona...</option>
 <option value="1">España</option>
</select>
```

*Required* works fine with `input text` but it doesn't work with `select`.

Is there a solution with Jquery Mobile?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the jQuery Validate plugin, the first `option` item **must** contain `value=""`.

```
<select id="comboPaises" name="comboPaises" data-mini="true" required="required">
   <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="">Selecciona...</option>
   <option value="1">España</option>
</select>
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/RX3MN/**

Otherwise, explain how you're doing the form validation.

Answer (score -1):

$("#formid").validate(); 
Then simply call validate on your form and it will not submit when "Choose" is selected.